# Run time & date checking in Background

Tags: android, date, time, android-datepicker, android-timepicker

I'm trying to develop an android application that let the user set a time range & a day and send  text messages according to the time range & day set by the user ,Now I've completed everything except that I don't know if there is a way to execute the code that checks time & date in background & even if the application is not running , please suggest me any ideas , thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to make Android call your app at a specific time. You can do this pretty simple like this:

```
AlarmManager.set( AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 
TWENTY_SECONDS, yourPendingIntent )
```

Then you should register a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) which will allow Android to send that intent to your application at specified time.

Comment: this link should help you..it's a very good tutorial on this problematic..
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html